# Quebra Limite de texto php

Tags: php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Conforme imagem acima, a postagem da notícia não está se limitando ao conteudo. Conforme os códigos php, deveria limitar até uns 70, porém dá mais de 1000 caracteres...

Olha os códigos...

home.php

```
<div id="bloco-tres">
    <h1>Outros Posts</h1>
    <?php
        foreach($query->selecaoLimit('4,5') as $outros){
    ?>
    <div class="outro">
        <a href="<?php echo $base.'/'.$outros['categoria'].'/'.$outros['slug'];?>" title="<?php echo $outros['titulo'];?>">
            <img src="posts/<?php echo $outros['exibicao'];?>" width="190" height="108" border="0"/>
            <span><?php echo $outros['titulo'];?></span>
            <p><?php echo $query->limitar($outros['conteudo'],70);?></p>
        </a>
    </div><!-- outro -->
   <?php }?>
</div><!-- termina bloco tres -->
```

Querys.class.php

```
<?php
class Querys extends BD{

    public function selecaoLimit($limite){
        $sqlLimite = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE status = '0' AND categoria != 'artigos' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limite";          
        return self::conn()->query($sqlLimite);
    }//método de seleção de dados limitado 


    public function selecaoArtigos($limite, $categoria){
        $sqlLimite = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE status = '0' AND categoria = '$categoria' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limite";            
        return self::conn()->query($sqlLimite);
    }//método de seleção de dados limitado


    public function limitar($str, $limita = 100, $limpar = true){
            if($limpar = true){
                $str = strip_tags($str);    
            }
            if(strlen($str) <= $limita){
                return $str;    
            }
            $limita_str = substr($str, 0, $limita);
            $ultimo = strrpos($limita_str, ' ');
            return substr($str, $ultimo).'...';
        }//TERMINA FUNCÇÃO PARA LIMITAR STRING
?>
```

Comment: troque return substr($str, $ultimo).'...'; por return substr($limita_str, $ultimo).'...';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está em:

```
$limita_str = substr($str, 0, $limita);
$ultimo = strrpos($limita_str, ' ');
return substr($str, $ultimo).'...';
```

Vamos traduzir o que está fazendo:

O `$limita_str` está limitando a `$str` desde o primeiro *caractere* (`0`) até o que for definido no `$limita` que é segundo argumento da função, logo de `0` até `$limita`.

O `$ultimo` na verdade é a posição do ultimo espaço () encontrado dentro do `$limita_str`.

O `return` retorna o texto do `$str` desde o `$ultimo` espaço () até o infinito, logo retorna o `$str` desde `$ultimo` até infinito.

---

Achou o problema?

O problema poderia simplesmente ser resolvido assim:

```
public function limitar($str, $limita = 100, $limpar = true){

       if($limpar = true){
           $str = strip_tags($str);    
       }

       return mb_substr($str, 0, $limita).'...';
}
```

> Requer o [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mbstring.setup.php), acredito que o `php-common` por padrão inclui isto.

Isso de fato não iria cortar até o último espaço, porém não vai quebrar um caractere no meio, ou seja não vai aparecer esses "`����`", como ocorre no `substr`, que não é multi-byte.

---

Se realmente quiser utilizar o `substr` e preservar a função como está, utilize:

```
public function limitar($str, $limita = 100, $limpar = true){
    if($limpar = true){
        $str = strip_tags($str);
    }
    if(strlen($str) <= $limita){
        return $str;
    }
    $limita_str = substr($str, 0, $limita);
    $ultimo = strrpos($limita_str, ' ');
    return substr($limita_str, 0, $ultimo).'...';
}
```

Comment: Resolvido Amigão!
Quebrou um galhão pra mim, muito obrigado chefe!